# Prevent SSMS single quote waiting for extra character (foreign character support)

Tags: ssms

I am using Sql Server Management Studio v2017.4 and recently the SQL text editor window has changed the way it handles a single quote character - it waits for you to type the next character and then converts it into a foreign language character.

I haven't been able to Google a fix for this and I can't find it in the Options. How can I revert to the settings where typing a single quote (apostrophe) gives you just that and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't caused by SSMS, but by having an international keyboard setting on Windows itself.